# How do I manually pause an activity in Android?

Tags: android

When you press the back button in Android it calls finish() under the hood, and I want it to be replaced with a pause behavior, and I have found no documentation that let's you trigger that manually.

EDIT: Ok, this needs more code I guess

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    int Action = event.getAction();
    if (Action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
         //Default Implementation calls finish();
         //I want to call Pause, which should call onPause and then send my app in the background !

          }
      }
}
```

I just tried onBackPressed, it doesn't even get hit with the above code on Android 4.3 at least. I tried manually calling onPause() but that just renders my app into an invalid state.

Comment: Use onBackPressed() and implement the behavior that you want ?

Comment: Just to add - `onBackPressed` has to have `@Override` on top of the function itself. Then do whatever you want with the handling of this keypress.

Comment: Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back key. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity... I want to implement pausing the activity :/

Comment: What do you mean by "pause behavior"? Can you describe this in more detail? Also, you should be careful about redefining the behavior of the Back button. This can cause a lot of confusion for your users.

Comment: I mean send app to background, pretty simple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To override the behavior of Back Button you can override `onBackPressed()` method in your `Activity` which is called when you press the back button:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   moveTaskToBack(true);  // "Hide" your current Activity
}
```

By using `moveTaskToBack(true)` your Activity is sent to background but there is no guarantee it will remain in the "pause" state, Android can kill it if it needs memory. I don't know why you want this behavior I think it would be better to save Activity state and recover it when you are back or simply, launch another Intent with the new Activityyou want to bring.

Comment: Thanks, aside from doing the process there, moveTaskToBack(true) works just like calling a theoretical Pause(). The code needs to go in KeyDown though (as I can do other key down processing as well)

Answer (score 0):

I think he is asking if it is possible to manually send the activity to onPause state. I don't think that is possible as long as the activity is in the foreground. You can, however launch an intent to send the phone back to the home screen or launch another activity to send the previous activity into the Paused state.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pause Activity when onbackpress() called i have done this to just calling on pause method it work for me

```
enter code here@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code with the `onBackPressed(){ }`

```
boolean mIsPaused = false;

final Thread workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      doA();
      checkPause();
      doB();
      checkPause();
      ...
   }
   }
});

private void checkPause() {
   while(isPaused()) {
      // you could also use the notify/wait pattern but that is probably needless complexity for this use case.
      Thread.sleep(50);
   }
}

private synchronized boolean isPaused() {
  return mIsPaused;
}

private synchronized void setPaused(boolean isPaused) {
  mIsPaused = isPaused;
}


pauseButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
      // disable any UI elements that need it
      setIsPaused(true);
   }
});

unPauseButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
      // re-enable any UI elements that need it
      setIsPaused(false);
   }
});
```